# AngularJs filter nested Array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, search, filter, nested

I have a Problem to get the Object when i search my nested Array for a string.
So in this Example iam searching for "Schirm".
When i pass it into the normal filter it show me that it is into the First area "Marketing" But i want to get it as Response.

Can somebody help me out?

This is my array:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":null,
      "Text":"Marketing",
      "Gruppen":[  
         {  
            "Id":null,
            "Text":"Werbeartikel",
            "Gruppen":[  
               {  
                  "Id":null,
                  "Text":"Werbegeschenk Hobby, Freizeit",
                  "Gruppen":[  
                     {  
                        "Id":"51004839",
                        "Text":"Taschenmesser (Werbeartikel)",
                        "Gruppen":null
                     },
                     {  
                        "Id":"51004843",
                        "Text":"Schirm (Werbeartikel)",
                        "Gruppen":null
                     },
                     {  
                        "Id":"51004845",
                        "Text":"Sportartikel (Werbeartikel)",
                        "Gruppen":null
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

This is my code snippet:

```
        <li ng-animate="'animate'" class="animate" ng-repeat="WarenGruppe in ActiveGruppe | filter:Search">
            <button ng-if="WarenGruppe.Id == undefined" type="button" ng-click="GetGruppen(WarenGruppe.Text)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" bs-tooltip="'Hier steht dann die Beschreibung.'">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {{WarenGruppe.Text}}
            </button>

        </li>
```

And here my Search Method:

```
 $scope.SearchForGroup = function (pSearchText) {
        var lGruppe = $filter('filter')($scope.WarenGruppenResponse.WarenGruppe, "Schirm")

    };
```

here is plunker demonstrating the problem  http://plnkr.co/edit/l0cnZQPAh2HXLX1yTnLl?p=info

Comment: could you include plunker of your full code

Comment: Iam searching my array like this:
var lGruppe = $filter('filter') $scope.WarenGruppenResponse.WarenGruppe, "Schirm")

iam getting the arrayobejct which contains the result. But i want the nested array as result

Comment: please specify your input and your output and the code you have tried. and please edit your question to insert the code

Comment: ive updated my question

Comment: is this how your code works http://plnkr.co/edit/l0cnZQPAh2HXLX1yTnLl ?? and you want to filter based on text inside all levels of nesting of Gruppen??

Comment: Exactly! when i click on marketing i will get into the next area where i get the Groups of "Marketing"

I want to search the whole array for the Text "Schirm" for example and get back the nested object

Comment: you might need to flatten the array before proceeding

Comment: But the array is very big. i only give you a snippet.

Comment: Mybe this is my soluton: ??

function(value, index, array): A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of the array, with the element, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.

Comment: yes you could write a recursive function to flatten the array and then use it in ng-repeat

Comment: can you help me out.

Comment: CAN ANYBODY HELP ME PLEASE